# How to add point one by one to serie in livechart

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

```
public ChartValues<ObservablePoint> Series1 { get; set; }

public void GeneratePlot(PlotInfo plotInfo)
{
    DataContext = null;

    Series1 = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
    Series1.AddRange(plotInfo.SeriesIn);

    DataContext = this;
}
```

How can I add point one and wait 200ms and add next point smoothly?

Now program's UI stop for few second and all points are shown.

Comment: [Documentation](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Constant%20Changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public async void GeneratePlot(PlotInfo plotInfo)
{
    Series1 = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
    DataContext = this;

    foreach (var x in plotInfo.SeriesIn)
    {
        Series1.Add(x);
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}
```